# could not find tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, macos-catalina

***I've installed Python 3.5.2 64 bit version.***

from python console

```
import struct
print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)
>>> 64
```

```
import sys
print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
>>> ('7fffffffffffffff', True)
```

from terminal(with virtual environment activated)

```
(venv) which python
>>> /Users/censored/PycharmProjects/untitled5/venv/bin/python
```

```
(venv) python --version
>>> Python 3.5.2
```

OS: 10.15.3 MacOS Catalina

Editor: Pycharm Professional 2019.3

pip: latest(20.0.2)

Error:

```
(venv) pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0 (from versions: 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
```

My co-worker who uses Ubuntu have no problem with installing tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0

What's the problem?

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document `https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu` said:

> Note: GPU support is available for Ubuntu and Windows with CUDA®-enabled cards.